# Intersection of 3 planes along a line

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, 3d

I have three planes:

\begin{align*}
\pi_1: x+y+z&=2\\
\pi_2: x+ay+2z&=3\\
\pi_3: x+a^2y+4z&=3+a
\end{align*}

I want to determine a such that the three planes intersect along a line. I do this by setting up the system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
x+y+z&=2\\
x+ay+2z&=3\\
x+a^2y+4z&=3+a
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

and solve for x, y and z. I subtract the first row from the second and third

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
x+y+z&=2\\
(a-1)y+z&=1\\
(a^2-1)y+3z&=1+a.
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

I subtract $(a+1)*\textrm{row}_1$ from the third row:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align*}
x+y+z&=2\\
(a-1)y+z&=1\\
(2-a)z&=1+a.
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

I think I am supposed to find an $a$ such that $0=0$ in the third row, but obviously there isn't any such $a$. Do I have the right idea about how to solve this? If so, where is my mistake?

Comment: You didn't subtract the RHS.

Comment: In the last equation there should be $...=-2(1+a)$

Comment: Ah, I see. So the RHS becomes 0. Where does $...=-2(1+a)$ come from though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean subtract $(a+1)$ times the second row from the third row.

After that the system become

$$x+y+z=2$$
$$(a-1)y+z=1$$
$$(2-a)z=0$$

If $a=2$, then we have $y+z=1$ and $x=1$ which is  a line.

If $a \ne 2$, then $z=0$, hence we have $(a-1)y=1$ and $x+y=2$, to be consistent, clearly $a \ne 1$, and we can solve for $y$ and $x$ uniquely.

Summary, $a=2$ for the solution to be a line.

Comment: Great answer. Is the line equal to $(1,1,0) + (0,-1,1)$?

Comment: You mean $(1,1,0)+t(0,-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes exactly! That's correct, right?

Comment: yup, that is correct, it is equation of a line. it satisfies both $x=1$ and $y+z=1-t+t=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea. 
Of yourse, in this case, there was only one parameter, and even that appeared in the form of simple expressions ($a$ and $a^2$). With more complicated problems, I suggest you start in a different way.

Compute the determinant of the matrix of coeeficients on the LHS:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a & 2 \\ 1 & a^2 & 4 \\  \end{pmatrix} = 4a+2+a^2-2a^2-4-a= -a^2+3a-2$$

This is zero iff $a=2$ or $a=1$. These are the only values to check: if the determinant is nonzero, then the system has a unique solution, so the planes intersect in a single point.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. How come nothing in particular happens at $a=1$ if the determinant is $0$? It seems there are unique solutions in that case.

Comment: In that case, there is no solution. Any two planes meet in a line, but the three lines must be parallel.

Comment: Ah, I see now. In one of the equations there is a 0=1 in this case.

Comment: Yes. The determinant is zero, so either there is no solution, or infinitely many. If $a=1$, then there is none, as you can obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

See, that from your system of equations you can obtain two lines:

$$l_1:\begin{cases}x=(a-2)t+1\\y=t\\z=(1-a)t+1\end{cases}$$
$$l_2:\begin{cases}x=\frac{5-a}{3}+\frac{a^2-4}{3}t\\y=t\\z=\frac{a+1}{3}+\frac{1-a^2}{3}t\end{cases}$$